# Вывод массива в ListBox

Tags: c#

Как сделать так, чтобы значения `Items` у `ListBox` заполнялись из массива?

Comment: В цикле перебрать массив добавляя в лист через `ListBox.Items.Add` не пробовали?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться методом [AddRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx), как пример:

```
string [] myArr = new string[4];

myArr[0] = "One";
myArr[1] = "Two";
myArr[2] = "Three";
myArr[3] = "Four";

myListBox.Items.AddRange(myArr);
```

Так вот сразу можно заполнить, если надо (сразу в листе):

```
myListBox.Items.AddRange(new object[]{"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six"});
```

Если не получится, то перебрать массив через цикл и добавить в лист:

```
string [] myArr = new string[4];

myArr[0] = "One";
myArr[1] = "Two";
myArr[2] = "Three";
myArr[3] = "Four";

myListBox.Items.Clear();

for (int i = 0; i < myArr.Length; i++) {
    myListBox.Items.Add(myArr[i].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте свойство `ListBox.DataSource` для отображения элементов, и `BindingList<T>` вместо массива, если хотите чтобы изменения отображались в `ListBox` без дополнительного шаманства.

```
var source = new BindingList<string>()
{
    "One", 
    "Two", 
    "Three", 
    "Four"
}
listBox1.DataSource = source;
```

Теперь любые строки добавленные в `source` будут добавлены и в `ListBox`. Если в массив состоит из составных объектов или структур, можно указать значение какого свойства должно быть выведено с помощью свойства `ListBox.DisplayMember`.

Можно конечно и так:

```
var source = new string []
{
    "One", 
    "Two", 
    "Three", 
    "Four"
}
listBox1.DataSource = source;
```

Только в этом случае для отображения изменений придется делать что-то такое:

```
listBox1.DataSource = null;
listBox1.Items.Clear();
source[0] = "NewValue";
listBox1.DataSource = source;
```

Или как предложили ранее, в режиме ручного редактирования содержимого.